# Vacuum of empty table takes 3 seconds

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

Running `vacuum` on some of our systems takes 3 seconds for an empty table:

```
create table t (c int);
vacuum t; -- 3 seconds
vacuum t; -- 3 seconds
vacuum t; -- 3 seconds
...
```

On my local installation it takes only milliseconds. Why is it so slow on some of our systems? What could the reason be? I tried to find what stalls the `vacuum` via using `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` but the stalling `vacuum` does not show up there.

One idea I have is that there are many table partitions on those systems. One example:

```
select count(*) from pg_class;                      -- 1.903.740
select count(*) from pg_class WHERE relkind  = 'r'; --   362.800
```

Could that be the reason? How can I find and fix the reason? This stalls autovacuum, as the wraparound-prevention vacuums take too long for all these table-partitions (that are 99.9% just all-frozen data or empty partitions) when they take several seconds for each partition when it should just take milliseconds.

Comment: very difficult to tell what can be the reason without knowing more details. But there is a view `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` which tracks the vacuum progress. It shows what stage is the vacuum progress in. Following are the different stages: `initializing, scanning heap, vacuuming indexes, vacuuming heap, cleaning up indexes, truncating heap, performing final cleanup` Maybe it helps you narrow down what part of the process is taking the longest. More details here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/progress-reporting.html

Comment: ty - as stated in my question, I did use that view and the vacuum is not there during the 3 seconds that it runs.

Comment: Missed that. Apologies. Just thinking out loud. Auto vacuum doesn't interfere with select, update, delete queries but as far as I remember, it doesn't run when you are creating indexes or truncating tables. Are any of these processes running in your other postgres installation?

Comment: Make the same number of table partitions on your local system, and see what happens.

Comment: @jjanes thank you for the suggestion. I created 2mio tables on the system where vacuum was instant and vacuum there now also takes 1 second. So this would indicate that the theory that the ~2mio objects in the DB make vacuum take 3 seconds instead of being finished instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `vacuum verbose t`, it will give you some details with timings included

Comment: great idea. no new findings unfortunately. both on the system where vacuum of an empty table takes 3 seconds as well where vacuum is instant it says the same: `vacuuming "public.t"
table "t": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 pages`